# Example that :$u\in C^\infty(U)$ not $u \in C^\infty(\overline{U})$ for elliptic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be arbitrary open subset in $\Bbb{R}^n$,Let $u \in H^1(U)$ be the solution for the following equation with $f\in C^\infty(U)$:

$$\int_U \nabla u \cdot\nabla \varphi = \int_U f\varphi$$

for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(U)$ .

By interior regularility result for elliptic equation we know $u \in C^\infty(U)$.But It needs not to be a solution that $u\in C(\overline{U})$.

Is there some good example  ?

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want an example of solution $u$ that is not in $C(\overline U)$, or an example of domain $U$ such that there is no solution in $C(\overline U)$?

Comment: @Arctic Char thank you ,I didn't realize there is subtle point here,I want a example that solution is not in  $C(\overline{U})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be the circle segment (in polar coordinates)
$$
U = \{ (r,\theta): \ r\in(0,1), \ \theta \in (0,\omega)\}
$$
with $\omega \in (\pi,2\pi)$. Then $U$ is non-convex. Define
$$
u(r,\theta) = r^{\pi/\omega} \sin(\pi\frac \theta\omega).
$$
Then $u\in H^1(U)$, $-\Delta u=0$, so it satisfies the requirements with $f=0$. But $u\not\in C^1(\bar u)$, as $|\nabla u(r,\theta)|\to\infty$ for $r\searrow0$.